# Sqlite update day on datetime

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to update just the day component on a datetime field on my sqlite database using:

```
UPDATE recur SET start_date = date('%d', '05')
```

I have read the documentation but cannot seem to figure out how to do this, can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are good examples in the [online documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). You're not calling the `date` function correctly. You need something like:

```
select date('now', 'start of month', '+4 days');
```

I'm not sure what date you need to start from, so I used `'now'`, but you could pass in a date field (from your database, for example) or a valid date string (like "2012-12-05", at least on my system).

### Edit

For example

```
select date('2012-12-08', 'start of month', '+4 days');
```

Will return:

```
2012-12-05
```

Keep in mind that sometimes when you're starting with a string it's easier to use string functions to do this type of manipulation. However using the date function will validate you are starting with a well formatted date.

### Edit 2

If you're also having trouble figuring out the `UPDATE` syntax, putting it all together you get:

```
UPDATE recur SET start_date = date(d, 'start of month', '+4 days')
WHERE d = date('2012-12-08');
```

I'm not sure what exactly you need for the `WHERE` clause so be sure your selecting the correct records before you run this.

Comment: I have a date in the format '2012-12-08', which I would like to update just the day component of e.g. change to '2012-12-25'

Comment: The value is in the database and I am trying to update it, I can select using strftime, just dont know how to update the existing date.

Comment: @Carl, added `UPDATE` statement example to answer.